# How to trigger build periodically in pipeline with different environment varaiables in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have here one pipeline that running test against app with specific environment variable and triggers at specific time.

what i want to do is to use the same pipeline to be executed periodically at different times but each build is with different environment variable.

here is sample of my jenkinsfile the run against only set of environment available at certain one time

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    mvnHome = tool name: 'myMvn', type: 'maven'
    mvnCMD = "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
    APP_NAME = 'test'
    APP_PACKAGE = 'test1'
    APP_ACTIVITY = 'test2'
  }

  agent {
    node {
      label 'master'
    }
  }

  triggers {
           cron('15 20 * * *')
  }

  stages {
    stage('SCM Checkout') {
      steps {
        git(branch: 'APP', url: 'https://gitlab.test.ba/amrka/framework.git', poll: true, credentialsId: 'GitlabCred')
      }
    }

    stage('Testing') {
    steps {
      catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
        sh(label: 'Test Process', script: "${mvnCMD} test")
        }
      }
    }


  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **parameterized-scheduler plugin**. In Jenkins dashboard, goto
`Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Parameterized Scheduler`.

To schedule a job at different times that needs to use different environments, you have to use the parameterized-scheduler plugin.

#### Parameter1

`H/20 * * * * %Parameter1` where `Parameter1` is your environment variable for a specific time you want.

#### Parameter2

`H/30 * * * * %Parameter2` where `Parameter2` is your a different environment variable for a specific time you want.

The parameters should be setup already for the parameterized-scheduler plugin to work. It can be used only for jobs with parameters.
Remember you have to have your parameters already setup because the plugin is visible only for jobs with parameters. [See more documentation including usage examples in the README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: great it seems interesting, can i path multiple parameters for each build

Comment: yes, of course. Check the documentation link I shared. It has excellent examples.

Comment: Nice pretty straight forward is there way to wrap all the parameters in like one array and just call the array instead of calling each parameters, incase of having many parameters 
GREETING = [ 'param1':vale1', 'params2':'value2'']
            */2 * * * * %GREETING